# Get request returns unfriendly response Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to perform a get request on [TCG Player](https://www.tcgplayer.com/) via `Requests` on `Python`. I checked the sites `robots.txt` which specifies:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-Delay: 10
Allow: /
Sitemap: https://www.tcgplayer.com/sitemap/index.xml
```

This is my first time seeing a `robots.txt` file.

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.tcgplayer.com"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

I cannot include `r.text` in my post because the character limit would be exceeded.

I would have expected to be recieve the HTML content of the webpage, but I got an 'unfriendly' response instead. What is the meaning of the text above? Is there a way to get the HTML so I can scrape the site?

By 'unfriendly' I mean:

> The HTML that is returned does not match the HTML that is produced by typing the URL into my web browser.

Comment: What do you see when you `print(r)`? I'd expect to see `=> <Response [200]>`

Comment: Yes, I do see that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to some server-side rendering of web content, as indicated by the empty `<div id="app"></div>` block in the scraped result. To properly handle such content, you will need to use a more advanced web scraping tool, like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). I'd recommend [this tutorial](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) to get started.

Comment: The HTML that is returned does not match the HTML that is produced by typing the URL into my web browser.

Comment: @karafar I've edited the answer - let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Would something like `Scrapy` work?

Comment: I personally haven't used `Scrapy`, but it seems possible - [this documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.htm) might work for you